# Does the eclipse kotlin plugin compile kotlin code?

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

Does the Eclipse Kotlin plugin compile kotlin code, or does it use the external kotlin compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kotlin eclipse's [build](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-eclipse/blob/master/kotlin-bundled-compiler/build.properties) includes kotlin compiler jars

> ```
>  lib/kotlin-compiler.jar,\
>  lib/allopen-compiler-plugin.jar,\
>  lib/kotlin-scripting-compiler.jar,\
>  lib/sam-with-receiver-compiler-plugin.jar,\
>  lib/noarg-compiler-plugin.jar,\
>  lib/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl.jar,\
> ```

And it uses special compilation using [light files](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-eclipse/blob/master/docs/dev-documentation.md)

> Kotlin plugin generates so called "light class files": Kotlin source code translated to bytecode declarations without bodies.
>
> Light classes are stored only in virtual memory and are managed by a special file system (see KotlinFileSystem , KotlinFileStore), so they do not affect the runtime.
>
> This method generates bytecode for the light class by calling the Kotlin compiler in special mode (KotlinLightClassGeneration.buildLightClasses). Basically, this allows Java to see Kotlin sources as special binary dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you don't need an external compiler , Eclipse does it 
https://beginnersbook.com/2017/12/kotlin-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 0):

Look at github, there is bundled compiler https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-eclipse/tree/master/kotlin-bundled-compiler.